# Out of stack space jquery (dataTables)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Been trying some MVC for the first time in VS2013, took a little of fiddling round to get a basic test/demo running. So I thought I'd try and have a go at getting dataTables working with it. However, when viewing the application index.cshtml, it keeps throwing an out of stack space error (tested with Chrome and IE8). I've tried creating an empty  in the  as well to placehold.

Here is my bundleconfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"));
```

_layout.cshtml

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And the relevant part of my own index.cshtml

```
<table class="table" id="plist">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.1)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.2)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.3)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.4)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.5)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.6)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.7)</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
   <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.1)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.2)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.3)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.4)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.5)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.6)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.7)</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.1 }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.1 }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.1 })
    </td>
</tr>
}</tbody>
</table>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
    $(document).ready(function() {$('#plist').dataTable();});
</script>
```

The IE debugger throws the exception here in the dataTables script file:

```
$.fn.dataTable = function ( opts ) {
    return $(this).dataTable( opts ).api();
};
```

I realise the problem is quite broad, but any common gotcha's I can check for please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
$.fn.dataTable = function ( opts ) {
    return $(this).dataTable( opts ).api();
};
```

appears to always call itself, which will cause infinite recursion, which will cause stack overflow (out of stack space) error.

Comment: Hmm, I deleted the *.js and then re-added it. Giving me a different issue now. I'll try and figure out where it is - looks like a config issue up to now. Appreciate the advice though.